Flutter ios development: do I need to install firebase-ios-sdk through xcode package manager?
I installed firebase-ios-sdk through Xcode package manager as specified in the firebase setup (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).
But when I run flutter build ios -v, the build fails with
Failed to build iOS app
[   +6 ms] Uncategorized (Xcode): Could not resolve package dependencies:
             downloaded archive of binary target 'openssl_grpc' from

'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/grpc/1.62.2/rc0/openssl_grpc.zip' does
             not contain a binary artifact.
             downloaded archive of binary target 'absl' from

'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/abseil/1.2024011601.1/rc0/absl.zip'
             does not contain a binary artifact.
             downloaded archive of binary target 'grpc' from
             'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/grpc/1.62.2/rc0/grpc.zip'
does not
             contain a binary artifact.
             fatalError
           
           
[   +9 ms] "flutter ios" took 243,811ms.
[  +30 ms] Encountered error while building for device.
[   +1 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit
           ...
           ...
[ +113 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 109ms
[        ] Running 1 shutdown hook
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +8 ms] exiting with code 1
liamhp@Liams-MacBook-Air my-app% 


However, if I don't install firebase-ios-sdk, I get a totally different error. So I'm not sure whether I'm actually supposed to have the sdk installed through xcode or just rely on pods/flutter pub.

PSA to future searchers- you don't need it, adding it may cause conflicts between swift package manager and pods
